# Proving weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> Suppose $\text{sup}\|f_n\|_p <+ \infty$ and $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere on $E$. I want to prove weak convergence $f_n \rightharpoonup f.$

I already have a proof that there exists a sub-sequence $\{f_{n_i}\}$ such that $f_{n_i}\rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $L^p.$

So in can reformulate my question as:

> How to show from the weak convergence of such sub-sequence the convergence of the whole sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that $\int f_ng \to \int fg$ for all $g \in L^{q}$ where $\frac 1 p+\frac  1 q=1$. For this it is enough to show that every subsequence of $(\int f_ng )$ has a subsequence converging to $\int fg$.

A sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ converges to a real number $a$ iff every subsequence of $(a_n)$ has a further subsequence converging to $a$. [You can give a proof  by contradiction].

Comment: can you expand a little? I don't understand.

Comment: @ann.boz I added some details when you were typing the comment.

Comment: and how does this prove what I want?

Comment: I did not prove that every subsequence weakly converges, I just proved that there exists one that does so. So I don't see how you proved what I want to prove.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understanding.. :(

Comment: @ann.boz Suppose $(a_n)$ does  not tend to $a$. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ and integers $n_1<n_2<...$ such that $|a_{n_k}-a| >\epsilon $ for all $k$. It is obvious from this that there is no subsequence of $(a_{n_k})$ which converges to $a$ (because the inequality holds for the subsequence also).

Comment: Ok let me see: if $f_n \to f$ a.e. then each of its sub-sequences does so. Hence by what I already know each sub-sequence of $(\int f_ng )$  has a sub-sub-sequence that converges to $\int fg$, and so by your result  $(\int f_ng )\to \int fg$. Is that it?

Comment: @ann.boz Yes, you got it!

Comment: thanks very much!